# Trigger Before Backup_Database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want Have a Trigger fire Before Backup DataBase (Server Scope Or DataBase Scope).

my Database is Mssql 2008

Is it Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you can trigger off a backup event, the list of DDL events is here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx and the event groups here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452.aspx

Comment: I Saw that, but it strange that mssql hasn't any Event For Backup ! is it possible to Work with EVENTDATA Function ?

Comment: Agreed, I would of expected an event group for it possibly. Denali doesn't show one up either.